# Create list, append data and transform to tuple: shortest code

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, tuples

I have a maybe stupid problem, but can't figure out how to solve it.
So basically what I'm trying to do is to:

- Create a list
- Add items to the list (stored in a second list)
- Transform the list into a tuple

So I thought I would do something like this:

```
anotherList = [2,5,8]
myTuple = tuple([1,2,3].extend(anotherList))
```

This does not work as it throws the error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

This makes sense, as the result of the `extend` operation is not a list. The problem is that I wasn't able to make it in a one line code, but only in a 4 lines code, like that:

```
anotherList = [2, 5, 8]
myList = [1, 2, 3]
myList.extend(anotherList)
myTuple = tuple(myList)
```

Is there a way to simplify this code? It looks unnecessarily long!

Comment: `list.extend()` returns `None`, always because the list is updated *in place*. Do not use it on a list literal, that's never going to result in something you want. Did you want to concatenate perhaps? Then use `[...] + anotherlist`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes exactly! I completely missed the `concatenate`, that's it!

Comment: @U9-Forward if concatenation would have come to my mind before I certainly would have not asked for this, my problem is that I couldn't figure out what to use in this case...

Comment: @toti08 Well, it's marked as duplicate, so what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use `list.extend()`, period. You are concatenating a list display (literal syntax) with another list instead, use `+`:

```
myTuple = tuple([1, 2, 3] + anotherList)
```

or you could convert just `anotherList` and prefix a tuple:

```
myTuple = (1, 2, 3) + tuple(anotherList)
```

Here the Python compiler can optimise and store the `(1, 2, 3)` as a constant with your code object. That initial tuple is created just once and reused across all executions.

`list.extend()` is intended to update an existing list object in-place via a reference to that list, but using it on a list literal means the resulting extended list has no remaining references and is discarded again.

In Python 3.5 and up you could also use the [new iterable unpacking syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations):

```
myTuple = (1, 2, 3, *anotherlist)
```

Note that no `tuple()` call is needed there, and *any* iterable type (not just a list) is supported. Python 2.7 is on it's last days, you do need to start planning to move away from it.

Answer (score 3):

You can add lists:

```
result = tuple([1,2,3] + [4,5,6])
```

So that'll be something like this:

```
anotherList = [2, 5, 8]
myList = [1, 2, 3]

myTuple = tuple(myList + anotherList)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's unclear tho, but...

Try this:

```
l=[2,5,8]
print(tuple([1,2,3]+l))
```

You can concatenate by `+`

Alternatively can do `*` (unpacking) in python 3:

```
print((*l, 1,2,3))
```

Or can do `chain` from `itertools`:

```
import itertools
print(tuple(itertools.chain(l, [1,2,3])))
```

Or `merge` from `heapq`:

```
from heapq import merge
print(tuple(merge(l,[1,2,3])))
```

Or `add` form `operator`:

```
import operator
print(tuple(operator.add(l, [1,2,3])))
```